# How can i display table row input value as Text format programmatically without using pSaveEditableRow in primeng?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using primeng table(p-cell editor) for adding new row in loop and I am displaying  input fields in a row to enter values and after filling the last column input field ..I need to display entire row output in text format...if I give pSaveEditableRow to the particular last column input(Inline) it is working but I want to use a function to display that row as text format with out using pSaveEditableRow .

Even i added the  **delete this.clonedCars[user.code]** in the function it is not working.

I am attaching the stack blitz URL for reference :-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-btx5eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `saveRowEdit` function of primeng Table instance

```
@ViewChild('dt') dt: Table;

onRowEditSave(event: any, car: Car, index: number) {
  this.dt.saveRowEdit(car, event.target);
  // delete this.clonedCars[car.code];
}
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-ie4yab?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

It's open source so you can inherit or override primeng code: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L3766